# Output is repeating the first dictionary every time

Tags: python, function, dictionary, format, output

I am supposed to be receiving the output for a reformatted dictionary from three separate inputs.

Current output:

```
{'JS': {'Paid': [200, 400, 500, 600]}, 'SK': {'Paid': [400, 1000, 1600]}}
{'JS': {'Paid': [200, 400, 500, 600]}, 'SK': {'Paid': [400, 1000, 1600]}}
{'JS': {'Paid': [200, 400, 500, 600]}, 'SK': {'Paid': [400, 1000, 1600]}}
```

Expected output:

```
print(buildCoverageDictionary(paidList1)) ->
{'JS': {'Paid': [200, 400, 500, 600]}, 'SK': {'Paid': [400, 1000, 1600]}}
print(buildCoverageDictionary(paidList2)) ->
{'JS': {'Paid': [200, 400, 500, 600]}, 'SK': {'Paid': [1010, 2000]}, 'MJ': {'Paid':
[5, 6, 7]}, 'ZF': {'Paid': [2660, 500]}}
print(buildCoverageDictionary(paidList3)) -> {'SK': {'Paid': [200, 400]}}
```

Two questions:

1. How can I edit the code to output the expected output?
2. How can I edit the code to not require me to individually reformat each dictionary and instead create a function that can properly reformat the dictionary no matter what the input is?

My code is as follows:

```
paidList1 = [["JS", 200, 400, 500, 600], ["SK", 400, 1000, 1600]]
paidList2 = [["JS", 200, 400, 500, 600], ["SK", 1010, 2000], ["MJ", 5, 6, 7], ["ZF", 2660, 500]]
paidList3 = [["SK", 200, 400]]


def buildCoverageDictionary(paidList):
    JS_dict = {'Paid': paidList1[0][1:5]}
    SK_dict = {'Paid': paidList1[1][1:4]}
    new_dict1 = {paidList1[0][0]: JS_dict, paidList1[1][0]: SK_dict}
    return new_dict1

    JS_dict = {'Paid': paidList2[0][1:5]}
    SK_dict = {'Paid': paidList2[1][1:3]}
    MJ_dict = {'Paid': paidList2[2][1:4]}
    ZF_dict = {'Paid': paidList2[3][1:3]}
    new_dict2 = {paidList2[0][0]: JS_dict, paidList2[1][0]: SK_dict, paidList2[2][0]: MJ_dict, paidList2[3][0]: ZF_dict}   
    return new_dict2
    
    SK_dict = {'Paid': paidList3[0][1:3]}
    ew_dict3 = {paidList3[0][0]: SK_dict}
    return new_dict3
    
print(buildCoverageDictionary(paidList1))
print(buildCoverageDictionary(paidList2))
print(buildCoverageDictionary(paidList3))
```

Comment: The function should use the parameter `paidList`, not refer specifically to all the variables.

Comment: Nothing after `return new_dict1` is executed -- `return` ends the function.

Comment: @Barmar how should i write it so that it will reformat the dictionary no matter the input?

Comment: Isn't that what the function parameter is for? There's obviously something wrong if you never use `paidList` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Barmar mentioned, `return` ends the functions and nothing after it is executed. You could try something like below, and keep it more flexible to changes in input, e.g. by looping on `paidList` and not hard coding the index, instead use `[1:]` which translates from index `1` till the last.

```py
paidList1 = [["JS", 200, 400, 500, 600], ["SK", 400, 1000, 1600]]
paidList2 = [["JS", 200, 400, 500, 600], ["SK", 1010, 2000], ["MJ", 5, 6, 7], ["ZF", 2660, 500]]
paidList3 = [["SK", 200, 400]]


def buildCoverageDictionary(paidList):
    output = {}
    for item in paidList:
        output[item[0]] = {'Paid': item[1:]}
    return output

print(buildCoverageDictionary(paidList1))
print(buildCoverageDictionary(paidList2))
print(buildCoverageDictionary(paidList3))
```

Using [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```py
def buildCoverageDictionary(paidList):
    return {item[0]: {'Paid': item[1:]} for item in paidList}
```

Comment: You can even transform it in a oneliner: `buildCoverageDictionary = lambda x: {y[0]:{"Paid":y[1:]} for y in x}`

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your first question:

```
paidList1 = [["JS", 200, 400, 500, 600], ["SK", 400, 1000, 1600]]
paidList2 = [["JS", 200, 400, 500, 600], ["SK", 1010, 2000], ["MJ", 5, 6, 7], ["ZF", 2660, 500]]
paidList3 = [["SK", 200, 400]]


def buildCoverageDictionary():
    JS_dict = {'Paid': paidList1[0][1:5]}
    SK_dict = {'Paid': paidList1[1][1:4]}
    new_dict1 = {paidList1[0][0]: JS_dict, paidList1[1][0]: SK_dict}
    print(new_dict1)

    JS_dict = {'Paid': paidList2[0][1:5]}
    SK_dict = {'Paid': paidList2[1][1:3]}
    MJ_dict = {'Paid': paidList2[2][1:4]}
    ZF_dict = {'Paid': paidList2[3][1:3]}
    new_dict2 = {paidList2[0][0]: JS_dict, paidList2[1][0]: SK_dict, paidList2[2][0]: MJ_dict, paidList2[3][0]: ZF_dict}
    print(new_dict2)

    SK_dict = {'Paid': paidList3[0][1:3]}
    new_dict3 = {paidList3[0][0]: SK_dict}
    print(new_dict3)


buildCoverageDictionary()
```

The changes I've made are:

- You don't use the parameter `paidList`, so I got rid of that.
- When you call the `return` function, it returns the thing you want and skips the rest of the function. So I replaced the `return`s with `print`.
- You spelled `new_dict3`(as `ew_dict3`) wrong.